# Гордость и спесь

Tags: этимология

Всем доброго здоровья! Помогите пожалуйста: в чем разница между словами **гордость** и **спесь**??? Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Ну вообще-то значения достаточно далекие друг от друга. Их трудно спутать и даже сравнивать, поэтому вопрос не совсем понятен.

Ну а если про значения:

СПЕСЬ, -и; ж.
Чрезмерное самомнение, уверенность в своём превосходстве перед другими; высокомерие, чванство, кичливость. Много спеси в ком-л. Сбить с кого-л. с.

ГОРДОСТЬ, -и; ж.
1. Чувство собственного достоинства, самоуважения. Национальная г. Мужская, девичья г. Рабочая, профессиональная г. Г. не позволяет принять чью-л. помощь. Г. мешает сделать что-л. Из гордости сделать что-л. 
2. Чувство удовлетворения от осознания достигнутых успехов, чувство превосходства в чём-л. Говорить с гордостью. Испытывать г. Г. отца, сына. Г. за чьи-л. успехи. Г. за науку. Г. за родину. С гордостью думать, говорить о ком-л.
3. Устар. и Разг. 
=Гордыня. Его отказ поняли как проявление гордости.
4. кого или чья.
О том, кем (чем) гордятся. Эти музыканты - слава и г. нашей страны. Ты моя радость, моя г.! Она была красой и гордостью семьи.

Тут даже трудно сказать, какое значение сравнивать.
Ну, допустив, второе. Общее то, что есть какое-то представление о собственном превосходстве. Но если у гордости это превосходство в чем-либо, то спесь - это личное превосходство ***перед кем-то***, обычно объективно не подкрепленное.